# Looping file names

Tags: .net, vb.net, file

I am trying to loop through all the files in a folder and list only the ones that contain a certain text in their filename. For example, while moving a new file `TEST.pdf` in the folder X, if there is already a file named `Test.pdf` in that folder then the new file should get renamed as `Test1.pdf` and so on. In order to do that first I am trying to find the count of all the existing files that contain the word `TEST` in their names.

This is the code I have so far:

```
For Each FoundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(varFolderPath, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchTopLevelOnly, varFileName & "*")
    If FoundFile.Contains(varFileName) Then                                                                             
        Response.Write(FoundFile & "</br>")
    End If
Next
```

The value of the variable `varFileName` being passed is `TEST.pdf`.

Currently, I have `Test.pdf`, `Test1.pdf` and `Test2.pdf` in the folder, but for some reason, this code, instead of listing all three files, just shows me `Test.pdf` in the response.

If I change my `For Each` loop to:

```
For Each fileName As String In Directory.GetFiles(varFolderPath, varFileName & "*")
```

then still I get the same result of only `TEST.pdf`. Why?

Comment: You do realize that `Test1.pdf` and `Test2.pdf` do *not* contain the string `Test.pdf` ?

Comment: Use a `ListBox` instead of `Response.Write(FoundFile & "</br>")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Currently i have Test.pdf, Test1.pdf and Test2.pdf in the folder but for some reason this code, instead of listing all three files, just shows me Test.pdf file in response.write.

Well that's simple. The name "Test1.pdf" doesn't contain "TEST.pdf", even if you view it case-insensitively.

Maybe you should be matching the extension and the non-extension parts separately - checking whether the extensions match *and* the first part of the filename starts with the first part of your search filename. So something like:

```
Dim extension = Path.GetExtension(varFileName)
Dim rest = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(varFileName)
If Path.GetExtension(FoundFile) = extension AndAlso _
   Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FoundFile).StartsWith(rest) Then
    Response.Write(FoundFile & "</br>")
End If
```

Comment: Thank you to every one for the quick responses. Yes, by separating the filename and its extension the code worked fine.